# Filtering with dplyr by using two separate selection criteria involving two columns

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to conditionally filter a data frame to extract the rows of interest. What I'm trying to do is different than generic conditional filtering in that it involves variable rules affecting the pairs of columns.

My reprex below simulates a `data.frame` which involves 4 samples: `Control`, `Drug_1`, `Drug_2`, and `Drug_3` and pairwise comparisons among them (difference is shown as the `p_value`). I'd like to use this piece of code in a function to potentially compare more than 4 groups. I tried combining the filtering criteria with `OR` operators but I ended with a rather ugly code.

My end goal is obtaining a `filtered_df` that shows all the rows in which variables `group1` and `group2` has the data pairs that is in my `comparisons` list. Any help is appreciated!

Best,
Atakan

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

# Make a mock data frame
gene <- "ABCD1"
group1 <- c("Control", "Control", "Control", "Drug_1", "Drug_1", "Drug_2")
group2 <- c("Drug_1", "Drug_2", "Drug_3", "Drug_2", "Drug_3", "Drug_3")
p_value <- c(0.4, 0.001, 0.003, 0.01, 0.3, 0.9)

df <- data.frame(gene, group1, group2, p_value)
df
#>    gene  group1 group2 p_value
#> 1 ABCD1 Control Drug_1   0.400
#> 2 ABCD1 Control Drug_2   0.001
#> 3 ABCD1 Control Drug_3   0.003
#> 4 ABCD1  Drug_1 Drug_2   0.010
#> 5 ABCD1  Drug_1 Drug_3   0.300
#> 6 ABCD1  Drug_2 Drug_3   0.900

# I'd like to filter rows when group1 and group2 matches the following pairs
comparisons <- list(c("Control", "Drug_1"), c("Control", "Drug_2"), c("Drug_2", "Drug_3"))


# I can filter by using one pair as follows:
filtered_df <- df %>%
  filter(group1 == comparisons[[1]][1] & group2 == comparisons[[1]][2])

filtered_df
#>    gene  group1 group2 p_value
#> 1 ABCD1 Control Drug_1     0.4
```

Created on 2018-06-29 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Do you need `map_df(comparisons, ~ df %>% filter(group1 == .x[1] & group2 == .x[2]))`

Comment: Or use a inner_join after converting the list to data.frame `do.call(rbind, comparisons) %>% as.data.frame %>% set_names(c("group1", "group2")) %>% inner_join(df)`

Comment: @akrun: `map_df` works. Can you please explain your answer a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this in a couple of ways.

**1)**  One way is to loop through the `list` ('comparisons') and then do the `filter` of the dataset individual and bind the output together (`map_df`)

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(comparisons, ~ df %>%
                         filter(group1 == .x[1] & group2 == .x[2]))
```

**2)**  Another option is to convert the `list` to a `data.frame` and do an `inner_join` with the first dataset

```
do.call(rbind, comparisons) %>% # rbind to a matrix
         as.data.frame %>% # convert to a data.frame
         set_names(c("group1", "group2")) %>% # change the column names
         inner_join(df) # and inner join
```

**3)** Or using `merge` from `base R` (similar to 2)

```
merge(df, as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, comparisons)),
            by.x = c("group1", "group2"), by.y = c("V1", "V2"))
```